# Apache FOP 2.6 Hindi Rendering issue

Tags: pdf-generation, apache-fop, hindi

I have a standalone program which uses Apache FOP 2.6 to write Hindi text to a PDF using Amiko font using the following font metric configuration (on CentOS 7 / Java 11):

```
<fop version="2.6">
    <renderers>
        <renderer mime="application/pdf">
            <fonts>
                <font metrics-url="Fonts/Amiko.xml" kerning="yes" embed-url="Fonts/Amiko.ttf" embedding-mode="full">
                    <font-triplet name="any" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                </font>
        <auto-detect/>
            </fonts>
        </renderer>
    </renderers>
</fop>
```

The Hindi text produced by the above is **correct** and shows up as follows in the PDF
[image]

If I remove `<auto-detect/>`, it changes to
[image]
which is **incorrect** in almost every word.

So, with the auto-detect tag in place and using the same method with generates the PDF but called from an application server (Wildfly 18 in my case), it always generates the incorrect hindi text as in the last image above. I have tried putting script attribute with deva/dev2 values but it further deteriorates the hindi text in the PDF.

Please help me understand what is missing when the same code is run through app server.

Comment: Do you get any warning message while using the configuration _without_ `<auto-detect/>`? Could you edit your question to include a simple block of Hindi text that could be used to reproduce the problem?

Comment: No need, issue is resolved. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for looking into this. The issue is resolved now.
It seems if additional font families are used in the XSL, they
cause this issue. In my case we needed only English & Hindi
together on the PDF, we removed the other fonts used from the
XSL & it is now producing the correct output.